# How to set folder icons of multiple folders automatically?

Tags: finder, icon

Setting up folder icons in macOS is a tedious process. which is "okay-ish" for small amount of folders but not feasible for large directories.

is their a script or an app that can do this automatically? like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900785/how-to-set-folder-icons-of-multiple-folders-automatically?rq=1) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796256/how-to-set-the-first-picture-of-every-folder-as-its-folder-icon)